# How to bind a yml map to a Java map in spring-boot configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am trying to follow this guide here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding

but I am struggling to get it to work.

I want to initialize a HashMap from a map defined in application.yml.

This is my last try at the yml-map definition:

```
symbols:
    symbolPairs.CombinationsAlpha="CombinationsAlpha"
    symbolPairs.[CombinationsAlpha]=aaabbb, bbbaaa, ccceee, dddggg
    symbolPairs.Combinations="CombinationsInteger"
    symbolPairs.[CombinationsAlpha]=000111, 222666, 999000, 151515
```

And this is my java class:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "symbols")
public class SymbolsConfig {
  private Map<String, List<String>> symbolPairs = new HashMap<>();
}
```

I want to have `"CombinationsAplha"` and `"CombinationsInteger"`injected as keys and the values as a List of Strings.
I am struggling to define the yml correctly.

The `@Data` annotation from [projectlombok](https://projectlombok.org/) generates getters and setters.

Comment: Does this have to be done at the class level? If I want to inject 2 maps from an application.yml file into a single class, do I have to create 1 class for each map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your yml structure isn't correct. Change your yml like this

```
symbols:
    symbolPairs.[CombinationsAlpha]: aaabbb, bbbaaa, ccceee, dddggg
    symbolPairs.[CombinationsInteger]: 000111, 222666, 999000, 151515
```

Here is the output

[image]